# "Изменения в Конституцию"

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Товарищ указал на эту ошибку в бюллетенях, а потом дал ссылку на [статью](https://www.kp.ru/online/news/3922894), в которой приводятся слова ректора института русского языка, что там якобы пропущено слово "вносимые", поэтому она считает, что в этой фразе всё правильно. Мне кажется, что её могли просто попросить притянуть за уши этот случай к норме. Хотя и не знаю, как у них на этом уровне обычно бывает, могу неправильно предполагать.

А вы как думаете?

Comment: Артем, в тексте действительно пропущено слово "вносимые". Вот только писать  с пропусками в бюллетене   нельзя. Это официальный документ. Поэтому согласен: ответ ректора притянут за уши. Хорошо, если ее попросили, а не она сама так думает.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, Серж! Да, с одной стороны, хорошо, если сама так не думает, а с другой — плохо, что непонятно, чему верить, а чему нет.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "верить"?

Comment: Ну верить, что человек говорит, что думает, или допускать, что то, что кому-то выгодно или ему самому.

Comment: А-а, мне кажется, что все-таки специалиста просто попросили притянуть за уши норму. Вот и все. Не может специалист такого уровня говорить такие вещи.

Comment: Я тоже согласен с тем, что разговорное выражение не должно было проникнуть в бюллетень. Непонятно только – неужели специалист такого уровня не боится испортить себе репутацию, навлекая бурю несогласия и обвинений в "продажности" со стороны других специалистов высокого уровня. Или всё же нет никакой ошибки? А если даже и есть, то никакой бури не последует?..

Comment: @Александр Стрелец, ошибка есть. А насчет репутации согласен с вами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как мне кажется, всё дело в том, что ошиблись **при использовании  существительных «поправка» и «изменение».** А что, надо их различать? По грамматике – да, надо, они только по значению синонимы (в какой-то мере).

Вариант  **«Вы одобряете поправки в конституцию»** по формальной грамматике был бы верен (да и в законе говорилось о поправках), здесь скорее стилистическая несочетаемость.  Мы ведь говорим: проголосовать за поправки в закон, одобрить поправки в бюджет.

Поэтому по стилю значительно лучше звучит вариант **"Вы одобряете изменения в Конституции РФ?"**

Примеры из Нацкорпуса (с В.п.):

Не успели депутаты одобрить **поправки в бюджет**, как Минфин заговорил о необходимости нового перераспределения расходов бюджета. [«Известия», 2002.07.01]

В ответ вице-премьер заметил, что  удалось проголосовать за  принятие короткой, но очень существенной **поправки в закон** "О таможенном тарифе". [«Еженедельный журнал», 2003.04.08]

**А теперь о грамматической разнице**, на которую не обратили внимания. Дело в том, что слово «поправка» дублирует падеж глагольного сочетания, а слово «изменение» имеет собственное управление падежом.

**1) Дублирование падежей для сущ. «поправка»:**

Принять поправки к Конституции – поправки (какие?) к Конституции.

Внести поправки в Конституцию – поправки  (какие?) в Конституцию.

**2) Собственное управление для сущ «изменение»**

Внести изменения в Конституцию –  **изменения в Конституцию**?

Нет, здесь нет дублирования падежа, но есть самостоятельное управление П.п., обозначенное в словаре: **изменения в Конституции.**

Управление в русском языке
Автор Д. Э. Розенталь.

**ИЗМЕНЕНИЕ** 2. [перемена; переделка] **в чём.** Изменения **в жизни** общества.

**3) Вывод**

Это грамматическая (а не стилистическая) ошибка при выборе падежа, а такие ошибки фиксируются на слух. Поэтому они недопустимы даже в разговорной речи.

Оправдать чем-либо такую ошибку сложно, лучше ее признать и извиниться.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Sharon! А почему вам тире больше нравится среднее? Обычно ставят большое. Я сделал двойку и тройку жирной, а то без этого у них скобка почему-то заменялась на точку, тем более что и единичка была жирная.

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, за правку и за то, что приняли ответ.  А я как раз зашла на форум и думаю: надо что-нибудь добавить  поубедительнее. Пишу, а  система шлет мне оранжевые предупреждения об условиях сохранения моей правки.  В общем, я решила  свое дополнение дать вторым ответом. А тире я тоже люблю большое, обычно копирую откуда-нибудь.

Answer (score 3):

Автор текста в бюллетене имел в виду: «Вы одобряете изменения, ВНОСИМЫЕ в Конституцию...»

Очевидно, что люди допускают такие конструкции не просто так. Конкретно в этом случае мы видим т.н. эллипсис, т.е. пропуск несущественных частей предложения, который не искажает смысла. Ср.: «Ты на работу?» (идёшь), «Мне, пожалуйста, чаю» (дайте). В прошлом считалось «безграмотным» говорить: «не переживай» (надо только: «не переживай 'что-то / за что-то'»); или: «книга содержит...» (надо только: «книга содержит в себе...»).

Да, «изменения в Конституцию» — это звучит слишком по-разговорному. Пожалуй, стоило бы воздержаться от такого фривольного слога в таком важном месте — и написать: «Изменения в КонституциИ».

Comment: *Спасибо, Марк!*

Answer (score 3):

Почему я считаю эту ошибку **технической**

Такую ошибку я считаю по своему происхождению  **технической**  (здесь не имеет смысла говорить о неграмотности как таковой).

Люди привыкли работать  **с поправками**,  по семантике это существительное  больше подходит, так как обозначает незначительные изменения и дополнения.

Но по стилю слово "поправки" не подошло, вместо него использовали "изменения", считая, что они полностью **взаимозаменяемы.** Но оказалось, что  это не так: не проверили, не учли.  Поэтому я считаю  ошибку **технической**.

А вот объяснить что-либо **пропуском слова нельзя**. Если пропустить  причастие в сочетании «изменения, вносимые в Конституцию", то связь управления возникает  между рядом стоящими словами, и эта связь должна быть корректной, проверенной по словарю.

Но ошибка, я думаю,  была вычислена **на слух**, так как она очевидна для носителей языка, вот поэтому выбор падежа так важен.

Что касается лингвистов, оправдывающих ошибку, то их я судить не берусь: трудно представить, какие взаимоотношения в таких структурах и между такими структурами. Мне кажется, что современная наука имеет больше возможностей для развития на периферии, чем в центре.

Comment: Я тоже сразу подумал, что тот падеж подходит к "поправкам", но не к стоящим там "измерениям".

Answer (score 2):

Артем, очень трудно отвечать по существу на такие вопросы, да при этом не влезая в политику.  Поэтому, извините, я в качестве предисловия приведу мысль Эль-Мюрида. Он высказался в том духе, что организация всего этого балагана  может объясняться только одним: все средства, отпущенные на проведение этого действа, разворовали еще в апреле. Отсюда  и эти чудовищные кабинки на лавочке, и текст поправок, которые вряд ли кто прочитал, и сами ляпы в бюллетене.

Я не сталкивался ранее ни с самой Русецкой, ни с её работами. Судя по всему, она даже не филолог - от слова "совсем". Её послужной список начинается работой логопедом после окончания педагогического института. А заканчивается докторской на тему преодоления дислексии. Так что появление её  во главе "Пушки" (это после Костомарова и Прохорова!) - свидетельство полного кризиса управления наукой.

И почему именно ей, человеку далекому от классической филологии, поручили давать ответ заслуженным авторам из института РЯ им. Виноградова (как это озвучено Ольгой Северской - надеюсь, пересказывать смысл их замечаний не надо) - одному Богу ведомо.

Во всяком случае ответ этот убивает полным отсутствием логики.

> В бюллетенях по поправках к Конституции Российской Федерации нет
> лингвистической ошибки, о которой ранее заявляли некоторые
> специалисты. Фокусировать свое внимание следует не на стилистике, а на
> смысле, которые в данном случае абсолютно прозрачен и понятен

Простите, тут либо-либо.
Либо ошибки нет - и тогда "фокусировать внимание" на смысле не надо, ибо он в этом случае передан верно.
Либо ошибка таки есть, но на неё следует смотреть сквозь пальцы, ибо "смысл прозрачен и понятен" - несмотря на наличие ошибки.

> Мне кажется, что её могли просто попросить притянуть за уши этот
> случай к норме.

Не могли - а попросили. Именно что за уши притянуть.
По сути своего ответа она оправдывает ошибку использованием разговорных, на грани двусмысленности, конструкций в официальном документе. Будь это реальный референдум (а не непонятного статуса опрос общественного мнения) - был бы скандал. А так - всё на тяп-ляп сойдет...

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я не в теме, там действительно "пушки", не "Пушкин" случайно?

Comment: *Я не в теме, там действительно "пушки", не "Пушкин" случайно?* - Я же кавычки поставил. ))) Да, в узких кругах ИРЯ Пушкина кличут Пушкой. Чтобы не путался с виноградовским, наверное. Кстати, журнал, ими издаваемы, носит название "Пушка" вполне официально.

Comment: Я понял. Но рассчитывал на самоочевидность этого прозвища. Плешка - плехановский,  Репинка - репиновский (СПб), Щука, Щукинка - щукинский, Табакерка опять же...

Comment: Всё, дошло))) Не врубился, что за "ИРЯ Пушкина" сначала.)

Answer (score 1):

В гугле можно обнаружить многочисленные примеры употребления выражений "предложить (принять / отклонить / подписать и т. п.) изменения в [закон / статью и т.п.]".

Такие примеры обнаруживаются не только в газетах, но и в официальных и научных изданиях (комментариях к законам, научных монографиях, учебных пособиях для студентов юридических вузов и т. п.). Первые примеры я нашёл в книгах 90-х годов издания, но массово распространилось это только в последние 10-15 лет.

Я считаю, что здесь мы столкнулись с канцеляритом (а не с просторечием) и предполагаю, что юристы воспринимают выражение типа "изменения в закон" как нечто неделимое целое, к которому применимы действия: предложить, принять, отклонить, подписать, одобрить и т. п. Если так, то я рискну предположить, что это основательно закрепится в канцелярите и поборется за место под солнцем литературного языка.

Comment: Спасибо! Похоже, что так и есть. Когда единичные слова разделяют косой чертой, обычно не ставят пробелы. Или Вам всё равно так больше нравится?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Знаю, но это только рекомендации частных лиц. Какое-то время я пытался им следовать, но потом решил, что мне так нравится больше.

Comment: @Sharon Я не слышал, как оправдывали другие "законотворческим жаргоном", я только собрал первичные факты в гугле и попытался их осознать. По поводу упражнений в остроумии: я не одобряю весь этот "хайп" (лучше бы такого типа критика началась лет 25 тому, а не сейчас).